# How to find on which element value dropped?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am trying to do simple drag and drop calculation.

user can drag UP and allowed to drop on BH / OT. But issue is couldn't find the ID where user drop, not working *onDrop()* func.

Suppose if UP(10) value draged and drop on BH(2), desire updated UP and BH value would be 0 and 12 respectively.

StackBlitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-drag-drop-issue-ydmwej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Tried Code:

```
<table
  class="hoverable child-table"
  style="background-color: white; border-radius: 8px; width: 100%;"
>
  <tr
    cdkDropList
    cdkDropListSortingDisabled
    cdkDropListLockAxis="x"
    cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
    (cdkDropListSorted)="f($event)"
    class="container"
  >
    <th style="background-color: rgb(244, 243, 243); max-width: 5%;">MON</th>

    <td
      style="font-family: 'belgrano', sans-serif; max-width: 5%; border-right: 1px solid black;"
    >
      NULL
    </td>

    <td
      id="BH"
      style="font-family: 'belgrano', sans-serif; max-width: 5%; border-left: 1px solid black;"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop('BH', $event)"
    >
      {{ BH }}
    </td>

    <td
      id="OT"
      style="font-family: 'belgrano', sans-serif; max-width: 5%;"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop('OT', $event)"
    >
      {{ OT }}
    </td>

    <td
      id="UP"
      class="draggable"
      style="font-family: 'belgrano', sans-serif; max-width: 5%; border-left: 1px solid black;"
    >
      <span
        cdkDrag
        ocColumnDrag
        (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved('UP', $event)"
        [cdkDragData]="employee.attendance?.[dateFormt(date)]['UP']"
        class="column"
      >
        {{ UP }}
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

TS:

```
  BH: number = 2;
  OT: number = 3;
  UP: number = 10;

  draggedTdId: string = '';
  draggedTdValue: any = '';

  dragMoved(tdId: string, e: CdkDragMove) {
    this.draggedTdId = tdId;
    this.draggedTdValue = e.source.data;
    console.log('1', tdId, e.source.data);
  }

  onDrop(tdId: string, event: any) {
    console.log('2', tdId, event);
    const draggedTdId = event.item.element.nativeElement.id;
    const draggedTdValue = event.item.data;

    const droppedTdId = tdId;
    
    console.log('Dragged TD:', draggedTdId, 'Value:', draggedTdValue);
    console.log('Dropped TD:', droppedTdId);
  }

  f(e: any) {
    console.log('sorted', e);
  }
```

Comment: Create a functional example on https://stackblitz.com/ for us and we will try to help u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **not** a response, only a brief explanation if how works with cdkDropList.

We have two directives (a directive makes that a tag becomes a "super tag" (a tag that have methods, properties and we can use events): cdkDragList -we can imagine like a "box"- and cdkDrag -we can imagine like a "ball" that there're inside the "box".

We can listen events happens to the "box" the cdkDropList: `cdkDropListDropped`, `cdkDropListEntered`, `cdkDropListExited` and `cdkDropListSorted`

We can listen events happens to the "balls", the cdkDrag: `cdkDragDropped`, `cdkDragEnded`, `cdkDragEntered`, `cdkDragMoved`,...

But **only** if the tag of .html have the directive (in your code I can not see it)

In the [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api) we can capture the arguments of the different events, so, when we have, e.g.

```
(cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)"
```

Our function onDrop will be like

```
onDrop(event:CdkDragDrop<T, any>){
   ...
}
```

See in the docs that the "Output" are defined like

> @Output('cdkDropListDropped') dropped: EventEmitter<**CdkDragDrop<T,
> any>**>

Well, the argument of the function is of kind `CdkDragDrop<T,any>` and have the properties (see the "interface" cdkDragDrop): `container`(the "box" where is dropped the "ball"), `currentIndex` (in wich index), `previousContainer` (the box from the "ball" leave), `previousIndex` (in wich index),...

Well, nobody talk about list. we can to have an unique box, two box, one box with a unique ball inside...,

Check your code. Really I don't know if you need three "box" with an unique "ball" in each, or an unique "box" with three "balls", but **rememeber** you can not use the event (cdkDropListDropped) if your tag is not a cdkDropList